# Microsoft Multi-factor Authentication not working with Remote Desktop in Microsoft Windows 2010

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, multi-factor-authentication

We have configured MFA for our users in our organization tenant in MS Office. We are login Microsoft Windows using our Azure AD login (work or school account) from our office local PCs.
In the daily routine, we need to remote our office other machines as well using our own Azure AD login. Now, the thing is, without configuring MFA, we can successfully do a remote of other machines. But after configuring MFA, it is being stopped and below message we are getting.

[image]

Could anybody help me to resolve this?